# How to set Jenkins installation file location?

Tags: jenkins

I want to set Jenkins file location to `E:\Programs\Jenkins` kind of location 
I'm using the command `java -jar jenkins.war`

How do i specify the file location with that commad

Comment: What do you mean by Jenkins' _file location_? Do you want the set up files to be extracted there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean jenkins home. Just specify JENKINS_HOME environment variable before launching jenkins. If you are using Windows go to user accounts configuration and change your environment variables. Add variable JENKINS_HOME with value E:\Programs\Jenkins.

Comment: Depends on windows version however.